# 'The talking head' fantasy book with a girl on a quest with a severed head and a sassy crow

Tags: story-identification

I feel like I'm going nuts because I swear this is what the book was called. I picked it up once at my local library years ago (around 2001, roughly). It was part of a series of fantasy books, young adult fantasy I believe, and it was very interesting and wittily written.

I remember a character (female, I think) travelling with a severed head that was enchanted to still be alive, and talk. There was a crow with the head, and he was a pretty sassy bastard, and I think they were all on a quest to reunite the head with its body but I can't be sure.

Sorry, I know that's not much to go on, but I've had a burning desire to read this series remembering how interesting it looked when I was younger. Dunno why I put it down in the first place.

I recall the cover vividly (it was a paperback). It featured the crow, with the girl standing in a background of long golden grass.

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18690056-bride-of-death

Comment: I got excited for a moment! But that book was first published only a few years ago, this was a while back. Thanks though!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm guessing Elizabeth Pewsey's *[The Talking Head](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1858812992)*. An AbeBooks review says:

> The talking head has red curls, green eyes, and a stroppy personality, and is accompanied by an equally tiresome talking raven. The head has been (by its own request) severed from its body during a battle between the Tuans and the Vemorians, and now demands to be restored to it. Gilly and Hal — who inadvertently walked through an arch and into a time outside time and space, and fell into conversation with a Tuan boy called Lugh — get landed with the job. Their adventures with and without the head are funny,exciting and unexpected."

The only cover I've found features a dark bird.

[image: Book cover with crow]

[ISFDB.org](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1855687) notes that this is part of the [Otherworld](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?28125) series.

For what it's worth, since you were fairly certain of the title, I went to ISFDB.org and searched by title. I noticed that one of them was marked as "young adult", so I did a bit more searching, found the book cover, and then eventually the AbeBooks reference.

Comment: THAT'S THE ONE!! I KNEW I had the title right!! No idea why it wasn't popping up on search engines, guess it was a common term and I needed the author's name.. thank you SO much!!

Comment: A Google search for `"the talking head" novel` also worked for me.

Comment: All a matter of finding the right keywords. :)